# share and extend enum list in python?

Tags: python, module

Suppose you have a common module and

```
it defines KEY_1, KEY_2.
```

You have other modules that use the common module and extend it in such a way that

```
module_a defines KEY_A1 KEY_A2
module_b defines KEY_B1 KEY_B2
```

I want to construct a list of all the keys somewhere:

```
[KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_A1, KEY_A2, KEY_B1, KEY_B2]
```

and access the list from everywhere.

I can start by defining a globally accessible list in the common module.
But how do I go about inserting the values from other modules?

-- module_a.py --

```
import common_module

KEY_A1 = 10
KEY_A2 = 11

common_module.the_list.append(KEY_A1)
common_module.the_list.append(KEY_A2)

defs..
classes..
```

woudln't KEY_A1 get appended multiple times if module_a.py is imported several times from other codes?

Comment: I think not.. it doesn't happen on the same runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code in a module is executed only once, the first time the module is imported.  That's the purpose of the `sys.modules` dictionary:  it records which modules have already been imported.  Every import checks `sys.modules` first.  If the name of module being imported is already a key in that dict, the module object is simply retrieved from that dict.  Else (the name of the module being imported is not in that dict) the module's file is *executed* to create the module object, and `sys.modules` is updated to record the new module name -> module object pair.